# Failed sniffing cluster state. Nest 7.4 accessing Elastic 7.2.0

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Whenever I try to provide a SniffingConnectionPool object to my ElasticClient setting an error pops up "Failed sniffing cluster state".

This is a very simple code that generates the error on my machine:

```
            var pool = new SniffingConnectionPool(new[] { new Uri("http://localhost:9200") });

            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
                .DefaultIndex("my_index");

            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            var searchResponse = client.Search<object>(s => s.Query(q => q.MatchAll()));
```

The weird thing is that if I remove **pool** and provide the **Uri** instead for the ConnectionSettings constructor it works just fine.

Thoughts? Thank you

Comment: What is your Elasticsearch.Net version?

Comment: 7.4 the same version of Nest.
I tried downgrading Nest to 7.2, it didn't make much sense but  I tried and it didn't work as well.

Comment: Can you share the exception?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the `.DebugInformation` on the failed request/response (if you set `.DisableDirectStreamining` on `ConnectionSettings` too, there will be more info), and also the network/http configuration from elasticsearch.yml config? I suspect the value returned in `http.publish_address` is not a public address, or the first `http.bound_address` is not a public address: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/df32cc63955cc49e4c90885280bfaeccafbfb83e/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Responses/Sniff/SniffResponse.cs#L38-L63

Comment: If you have only a single node cluster, the `SingleNodeConnectionPool` will be the best to use

Comment: I ended up using Static but the SingleNode was a good option too. I'll try to investigate it more later, and provide the debuginformation here